# ListView ignoring drag and drop when setting a ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have set up a ListView to manage tabs on my app. So users can drag and drop tabs to new instances of the app and reorder tabs. All goes great until I set up a ControlTemplate for the Itens at the ListView.

I used ControlTemplate because when I add a ListView.ItemTemplate directly it won`t work (it does not affect the listview item). So before adding a new item I use this:

```
tab.Template = (ControlTemplate)this.Resources["listViewItemTemplate"];
```

So the tabs is looking great, but all the functions that used to work (like drag and drop) isn't working anymore. When I remove the ControlTemplate the ListView show only one little string.

This is what is happening
[image: This is what is happening]

My ListView Code:

```
<ListView x:Name="TabsListView" 
     CanDragItems="True"
     AllowDrop="True"
     DragEnter="TabsListView_DragEnter"
     Drop="TabsListView_Drop"
     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled
     CanReorderItems="True"
     DragItemsStarting="TabsListView_DragItemsStarting"
     ItemClick="TabsListView_ItemClick" >
```

I know for sure that the issue isn't on the drag and drop method.

To create a new item I just use Add. Of course I checked every single item inside ControlTemplate to know that it is not blocking anything.

The control template is:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="listViewItemTemplate" >
    <ListViewItem>
        <Grid Tapped="Grid_Tapped" Width="180" Margin="-12,-12,-12,0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,6,0,0"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </ListViewItem>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: That's because you shouldn't be changing the `ContentTemplate`... It's got all the hooks for the drag-n-drop to work and you replaced it with a data template...

Comment: But @JustinXL I need to include some style and other info to the ListView Item. How can I make it without ContentTemplate?

Comment: If you want different styling, do it in the Style of the listview item.

Comment: I don`t think it is possible to insert a button or right click menu context from the Style. I get your point, but this will not work for me. Gonna try again to change it to DataTemplate, but every time I add a new item id did not follow the DataTemplate I had set.

Comment: Both sound possible to me. But if you really want your own control template, you should consider building your own drag n drop logic.

Comment: I get the ControlTemplate don't work for Drag and Drop. So I tried to put it with DataTemplate: `TabsListView.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["listViewItemTemplateData"];`, but this does not affect anything. It is like I hadn't set a ItemTemplate.

Comment: Why are you trying to set the item template in code?

Comment: Because doing it on the XAML isn't working. It does not set the template.

Comment: You are doing it wrong dude. You are down to the wrong path. First fix why it isn't working.

Comment: Man I don't get it, I just said it won't work. The `<ListView.ItemTemplate>` does not work, and I need that to work. (I can`t create buttons, events handles and other stuff like that, what I need for every ListView.Item, from the Style Resoruces).

Comment: Tell me what I'm doing wrong, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are using `ControlTemplate` and embedding a `ListViewItem` in there. `ListViewItems` are created automatically by the control to contain the items, and `ItemTemplate` is a template of the **contents** of this container. So it should look like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="listViewItemTemplate" >
    <Grid Tapped="Grid_Tapped" Width="180" Margin="-12,-12,-12,0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,6,0,0"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<ListView ... 
      ItemTemplate="{ThemeResource listViewItemTemplate}">
        ...
</ListView>
```

Furthermore, if you want to style the `ListViewItem` (the container), you can create a style with `TargetType="ListViewItem"` and set it as `ListView.ItemContainerStyle`.

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="TabListViewItemContainerStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Grid x:Name="ContentBorder">
                    ... some template with ContentPresenter:
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ... />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ListView ...
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TabListViewItemContainerStyle}">
     ...
</ListView>
```

You can find the default style in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.15063.0\Generic`

### Update

I have checked the code and found the problem. What you are actually doing is adding `ListViewItems` directly in code:

```
ListViewItem tab = new ListViewItem();
DataModel model = new DataModel();
model.Name = $"NewTab {counter}";
tab.DataContext = model;
tab.Content = model.ToString();
TabsListView.Items.Add(tab);
```

Unfortunately this does not work, because when `ListView` sees an item that is of type `ListViewItem`, it just adds it to the list, but ItemTemplate doesn't apply to it, because that is applied only when the items are not `UIElement` but rather a custom class. If you use `DataModel` directly, `ItemTemplate` will be applied as expected:

```
DataModel model = new DataModel();
model.Name = $"NewTab {counter}";
TabsListView.Items.Add(model);
```

`ListView` encounters `DataModel`, knows that just a class not a `UIElement`, so it internally creates a `ListViewItem`, applies `ItemContainerStyle` to it and then uses the `ItemTemplate` to create the UI that will be displayed inside the ListViewItem's `ContentPresenter`. It is better to use this approach as it gives you better decoupling as you don't have to create UI-based classes in the code-behind and you get more control (as you can change both the style of the item as well as the container).

Comment: I followed you precisely, doing DataTemplate, removing the embedding ListViewItem and putting `ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listViewItemTemplate}"` inside the <ListView>.
Yet, I didn't succeed. And the application behave like there is no Item Template. I double check the names and everything is looking good.

Comment: That is very unusual. I have this exact solution in my app which implements Tabbed UI as well. Could you try to implement it in a simple solution and post it here so that I can look at the code itself?

Comment: Here is the GitHub link for a simple solution with all the things that could possible affect it: [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/vtnorton/TabbedUWP)

Comment: I have updated my answer with an explanation of what I have found :-)

Comment: A pretty simple solution! Thank you Martin. Gonna improve the code and update the GitHub Repository with it so other people can use it. Can't thank you enough!

Comment: You are wolcome, happy coding :-)